# Coloring rows based on row values in Dynatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, dynatable

I'm trying to color rows based on "Status" which can be Red/Green. 
Using dynatable to generate table rows based from JSON data.

The problem is that whenever I call the following code from dynatable, it always gets overwritten by dyntable.process();

```
$('#mytable tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Red') {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
});
```

My index.php:
http://pastie.org/10389654

My index.js:
http://pastie.org/10389656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this point of the docs : [Documentation - Event](http://www.dynatable.com/#event-hooks)

And use probably the `dynatable:beforeUpdate` event

Some approach like this :

```
   var dynatable = $('#mytable').dynatable({
  dataset: {
      ajax: true,
      ajaxUrl: './api.php',
      ajaxOnLoad: true,
      records: []
  },
  params: {
      records: 'data'
  },
  features: {
      paginate: false,
      sort: false,
      pushState: false,
      search: false,
      recordCount: false,
      perPageSelect: false
  }
}).data('dynatable').bind('dynatable:afterProcess', changeColor);
```

And then your function

```
function changeColor() {
    $('#mytable tr td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Red') {
            $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#f00');
        }
    });
}
```